# Illustrator changes the page-information text during saving file as pdf

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf

I need to create PDF-Files for print and add page information to it (there is an option during the exporting pdf).
Whenever I save it as PDF there is something like: "ai165599074342" added in front of the page information.
I export the same file with some options with another computer and there is noting added extra to the Page Information.
Any Idia how to prevent it?

Comment: See this article on the Adobe help site: [Fix network and removable media issues](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/kb/illustrator-support-networks-removable-media.html)

Comment: You can write your Text as an answer. I needed to dig for almost 3 days tell I could find it out.

Comment: The problem is that your question is basically a tech support one. Answers to questions like this are rarely helpful to others here since they are very much dependent on things such as hardware and your local setup, that can't really be reproduced. Because of that, tech support is generally considered to be off-topic here. Sorry about that.

Comment: Might be worthwhile pointing out that Adobe Tech Support doesn't support working with Illustrator files over networks, simply because there are too many variables in how networks can be set up. Some might work, and some might not.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found it.
It happenes always if I save the data on Network.
So, I have to save it locally first and the AI won't add extra text to the Page Information.
But Why? I have no IDIA